# Lifetime of pointers filled in by GetAcceptExSockaddrs

Tags: c++, winapi, winsock2

The MSDN page on [GetAcceptExSockaddrs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms738516(v=vs.85).aspx) does not specify anything about freeing  the returned address pointers `LocalSockaddr` and `RemoteSockaddr`. Attempt to free them results in an error reported by the debug heap. So I assume these are some static pointers. But in that case could anyone with more knowledge provide some information about their lifetime? Is this the usual *valid until next call* thing?

To be more precise - the function fills in pointers to pointers, that is why this is not the case of simply passing in pointers to stack variables. Consider this snippet:

```
INT LocalAddressLength = 0, RemoteAddressLength = 0;
LPSOCKADDR LocalAddress = nullptr, RemoteAddress = nullptr;
m_pGetAcceptExSockaddrs(buf, m_nReceiveBufferSize, sizeof(SOCKADDR_IN) + 16, sizeof(SOCKADDR_IN) + 16, &LocalAddress, &LocalAddressLength, &RemoteAddress, &RemoteAddressLength);
```

The function itself sets the pointers instead of just filling in their contents.

Comment: Huh? These are _your_ pointers that you should provide for the function to write data into. It's your responsibility to manage them.

Comment: @SingerOfTheFall the parameters are pointers to pointers - they are filled in by the function and if I try a plain `delete` I get an assertion, so I don't think it is that trivial. I mean - Microsoft usually specifies if you should use the standard freeing mechanisms, or `CoTaskMemFree` or something else.

Comment: The page you linked says, e.g., "RemoteSockaddr [out] A pointer to the sockaddr structure", what makes you think about pointers to pointers?

Comment: @SingerOfTheFall But if you look at the function signature it says `LPSOCKADDR *RemoteSockaddr` - a pointer to `LPSOCKADDR` which is a pointer to `SOCKADDR` implying a pointer to pointer. So even MSDN is unclear in this case.

Comment: @RudolfsBundulis Are the pointers returned are non-null? Did you get the pointer to a function via  WSAIoctl?

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius yes, the pointers are valid and contain valid data, and the function was properly loaded with `WSAIoctl`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The documentation does not tell you how to free the memory, because you don't need to free the memory. The documentation says:

> The GetAcceptExSockaddrs function parses the data obtained from a call to the AcceptEx function and passes the local and remote addresses to a sockaddr structure.

That's pretty poorly worded in my view, but what I expect that it means is that the addresses returned point to somewhere inside the supplied buffer. In other words, no new memory has been allocated, and the addresses returned by `GetAcceptExSockaddrs` are valid so long as the supplied buffer is valid.

Comment: I assumed this as well - but the pointers filled in are way out of the range of supplied data buffer that was filled in by `AcceptEx` so I still presume that there is simply a static variable in the function that gets filled in by this function and the address of it is put in the provided pointer but sadly I have no confirmation of this. And yeah - I totally agree that MSDN is very poorly worded in this case.

Comment: Well, that is very bizarre indeed. I think you have to assume though that you should not attempt to free this memory.

Comment: Sorry I was wrong - I don't remember if I overlooked the watch window or something but after a few runs it seems that this is correct - the returned pointers actually point to the memory inside the buffer passed to `AcceptEx` with a weird offset. Thanks:)